# Javascript array to not print/output NaN or 0

Tags: javascript, html

How do I hide/not print/output when number1 or number2 is NaN or 0 just by modifying below

```
document.getElementById('inputTextToSave').innerHTML =  parseFloat(number1).toFixed(3) + "," + parseFloat(number2).toFixed(3);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var n1 = parseFloat(number1),
    n2 = parseFloat(number2),
    list = [];

// add values to array if they're not NaN or > 0
if (n1) {
    list.push(n1);
}

if (n2) {
    list.push(n2);
}

// combine values into a string separated with commas    
document.getElementById('inputTextToSave').innerHTML = list.join(",");
```

Comment: how would use a "\n" after the second number? I tried parseFloatt(number1)"\n", but did not work

Comment: If you need to enter `\n` after the second number, just use `document.getElementById('inputTextToSave').innerHTML = list.join(",") + "\n";`

Comment: If what you're after is a newline, you're probably better off using `document.getElementById('inputTextToSave').innerHTML = list.join(",") + "<br/>";` to add a line break.

Comment: sorry there are more number. the idea is to use "\n" for every other number i.e.    2222, 2222 "\n" 3333, 3333 "\n" 4444, 4444 "\n" ....

Answer (score 0):

Try this condition  `number1.trim()` is validate `NaN` And `parseFloat(number1) > 0` validate `0`

```
if (number1.trim() && parseFloat(number1) > 0 && number2.trim() && parseFloat(number2) > 0) {
  document.getElementById('inputTextToSave').innerHTML = parseFloat(number1).toFixed(3) + "," + parseFloat(number2).toFixed(3);
}
```

Comment: @AlexaAtna can you explain what you are needed?

Answer (score 0):

You could collect your values in an array, filter the data with a check for truthyness and map the calculation and fixing. Then join the array for getting a single string. If the string is not empty, assign the value to the HTML element with the given id.

```js
function setResult(array, id) {
    var result = array.filter(a => +a).map(a => (2 * a).toFixed(3)).join(', ');
    if (result) {
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = result;
    }
}

setResult([0, 0], 'example0');
setResult([10], 'example1');
setResult([10, 0], 'example2');
setResult([10, 20, 30], 'example3');
```

```html
<div id="example0">-</div>
<div id="example1">-</div>
<div id="example2">-</div>
<div id="example3">-</div>
```